# How concat many attribute values for xml?

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, wso2

SOAP Message:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>   
        <field_21>
            <row StartDate="2017-01-01" EndDate="2017-01-07" DaysCount="7" Diagnoz="A00.0"/>
            <row StartDate="2019-02-01" EndDate="2019-02-07" DaysCount="8" Diagnoz="A10.0"/>
        </field_21>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>            
            <xsl:value-of select="string-join(
               concat(//field_21/row/@StartDate, ' ', 
                        //field_21/row/@EndDate, ' ', 
                        //field_21/row/@DaysCount, ' ', 
                        //field_21/row/@Diagnoz), ';')"/>
        </result>         
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<result xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">2017-01-01 2017-01-07 7 A00.0</result>
```

The result that I need:

```
<result xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">2017-01-01 2017-01-07 7 A00.0; 2019-02-01 2019-02-07 8 A10.0</result>
```

Tell me how to correct my conversion to get the required result

Comment: can you use 2.0 or 1.0 only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slightly confusing because your stylesheet has `version="1.0"` in it, but `string-join` is only available in XSLT 2.0. However, if you were using XSLT 2.0, I would expect the `concat` to failure because `//field_21/row/@StartDate` returns multiple nodes, which would not be allowed in XSLT 2.0

But, if you are indeed using XSLT 2.0, you could write the expression like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-join(//field_21/row/concat(@StartDate, ' ', @EndDate, ' ', @DaysCount, ' ', @Diagnoz), ';')"/>
```

Or, like this, to take advantage of the `separator` attribute available in XSLT 2.0.

```
<xsl:value-of select="//field_21/row/concat(@StartDate, ' ', @EndDate, ' ', @DaysCount, ' ', @Diagnoz)" separator="; " />
```

If, however, you can only use XSLT 1.0, you would have to use `xsl:for-each` (or `xsl:apply-templates`

```
<xsl:for-each select="//field_21/row">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">; </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@StartDate, ' ', @EndDate, ' ', @DaysCount, ' ', @Diagnoz)" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: For 2.0 you can use like `<xsl:value-of select="string-join(for $val in /*:Envelope/*:Body/field_21/row return concat($val/@StartDate, ' ', $val/@EndDate, ' ',$val/@DaysCount, ' ',$val/@Diagnoz),', ')"/>`